# RESTful Authentication of an Android client

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, wildfly-8

I'm developing a web server (Using J2EE/Wildfly 8.2) with a RESTful API for the Android clients.  To authenticate the connected client I would like to use a token (OAUTH2 or whatever is appropriate) from that client rather have to deal with the messy password admin in the server.

Could someone point me at a good example.  Ideally it would use the Google account on the Android device as most users (I would think) have an active Google account.

As always, many thanks for your help getting me started on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be helpful for you to take a look at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com). In your backend, you can use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs. Since you are specifically interested in the social login functionality, this is the way you would do it with Stormpath:

There are two options here...

1. You can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/). It supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login.
2. You can create and host your your own social login forms. In this case, your front end will display the login buttons. When the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials to the backend-end where you will need to execute code similar to what was [documented here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/social-integrations/)